# OnClick radio button show hide div angular js

Tags: angularjs

My code is ,

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
  </form>

  <div id="reddiv">Red Selected</div>
  <div id="greendiv">Green Selected</div>
  <div id="bluediv">Blue Selected</div>
```

my script is

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.color = 'blue';
    if ($scope.color == 'blue') {
        //blue div show
    }
    else if($scope.color == 'green') {
        //green div show
    } 
    else {
        //red div show
    }
}
```

i need to show based on radio button click , I tried a piece of code above i given , any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular way would be to use `ngShow`/`ngHide`/`ngIf` directives to show corresponding div. Consider this example:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.color = 'blue';
    $scope.isShown = function(color) {
        return color === $scope.color;
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="isShown('red')">Red Selected</div>
<div ng-show="isShown('green')">Green Selected</div>
<div ng-show="isShown('blue')">Blue Selected</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yU6Oj36u9xSJdLwKJLTZ?p=preview

Also very important that `ng-controller="Ctrl"` should be moved higher then your form, because dives should be in the same scope.

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to change the view directly from your controller. This is not the angular way. Pull the model state from the view out of the controller. For example:

```
<div ng-show="color == 'red'">Red Selected</div>
<div ng-show="color == 'green'">Green Selected</div>
<div ng-show="color == 'blue'">Blue Selected</div>
```