# unable to compare ng-model value and value of radio button and "ng-show" a message

Tags: angularjs

In the form I am designing, I would like to show a `< input="date">` field for anniversary-date if the user selects a radio button with `value = "married"`.

For now, I have replaced the same with a div saying "Anniversary date input will appear here".

My problem is that, `user.maritalStatus == 'married'` is always set to false. 
I know this because `ng-show` doesn't show the message. `ng-hide` shows this message.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="btn-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="maritalStatusRadioBtn" value="single" data-ng-model="user.maritalStatus">Single
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="radio" name="maritalStatusRadioBtn" value="married" data-ng-model="user.maritalStatus">Married
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- following does NOT work -->
<div data-ng-show="user.maritalStatus == 'married'">Anniversary date input will appear here</div>
```

I followed these examples:

- http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ
- [OnClick radio button show hide div angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400456/onclick-radio-button-show-hide-div-angular-js) - the one answered by michael (highest upvotes)

but I am not getting it to work.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/vipulnj/pen/KperpO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap your content inside `<div ng-app=""> </div>` if you have not already

Comment: Wrapping does not help.

Comment: could you give a code pen or jsfiddle example of your  problem?

Comment: Added the link. Please check.

Comment: @vipulnj, Are you sure you wrapped all your markup?  I just tried this on your fiddle and it fixed it.

Comment: @BuhBuh can you share the code with the wrap part you added? I added it and didn't work. Hence, codepen-ed without the `wrap`.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Didn't wrap properly in the codepen example. But, this is a view of a Single Page application and the `ng-app="appName"` has been declared in the index.html. Still not working. In the same form, the angular features are working fine.

Comment: @ the downvoter: Please explain your reason for downvoting.